# Optimizing CASE WHEN statement in SQL Server WHERE clause condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I am rewriting my sql to reduce the cost of execution and wondering if there is an efficient way to write the below CASE WHEN statements used in WHERE condition:

```
SELECT l.*,tg.*
FROM  RefTable tg, 
      InputTbl l
WHERE tg.areascheme = l.areascheme
  AND tg.countrycode = l.strareabriefnamel1  
  AND ( CASE WHEN l.strareabriefnamel2 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tg.areacode END ) = COALESCE( l.strareabriefnamel2,'' )
  AND ( CASE WHEN l.strareabriefnamel3 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tg.subareaname END ) = COALESCE( l.strareabriefnamel3,'' )
  AND ( CASE WHEN l.strareabriefnamel4 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tg.postalname END ) = COALESCE( l.strareabriefnamel4,'' )
  option( MAXDOP 0 );
```

Execution Plan :-
[image]

More Details :-

InputTable( 466K records ) has total four fields which participate in JOIN logic and there are total 16 possible ( NULL,NOT NULL )combinations.

```
L1,  L2,  L3,  L4
NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
NULL,NULL,NULL,NOT NULL
NULL,NULL,NOT NULL, NULL
NULL,NULL,NOT NULL,NOT NULL
NULL,NOT NULL,NULL,NULL
NULL,NOT NULL,NULL, NOT NULL
NULL,NOT NULL, NOT NULL,NULL
NULL,NOT NULL,NOT NULL,NOT NULL
NOT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
NOT NULL,NULL,NULL,NOT NULL
NOT NULL,NULL,NOT NULL,NULL
NOT NULL,NULL,NOT NULL,NOT NULL
NOT NULL,NOT NULL,NULL,NULL
NOT NULL,NOT NULL,NULL,NOT NULL
NOT NULL,NOT NULL,NOT NULL,NULL
NOT NULL,NOT NULL,NOT NULL,NOT NULL
```

RefTable( 45k records ) which will participate in the JOIN logic with InputTable is generating the resultset based on the above criteria is producing around 351 million rows.

My input data is currently meeting only two scenarios.

InputTable :-

```
NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL - 225776 rows
NOT NULL, NOT NULL, NULL, NULL - 240360 rows
```

Any inputs would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the performance issue you found while using case-when? If you are going to check only NULL you can very well use coalesce as you are using in the other condition...

Comment: strareabriefnamel2 field values can be both NULL and NOT NULL. Need to consider both conditions and use them in the WHERE clause...

Comment: But based on your example you can just use iif...

Comment: @KannanKandasamy . . . Although I'm not a fan of `CASE` in `WHERE` clauses, `IIF()` is worse because it is not standard SQL.

Comment: No, if strareabriefnamel2 is NULL I am actually joining empty string on both sides but when strareabriefnamel2 is NOT NULL there would be two different NOT NULL values on both sides....

Comment: The only possible scenario here is SCAN for both tables. Note, you have no predefined filters at all. But - yes - where clause is horrible for performance.

Comment: It is impossible to improve a query unless you know what is (if there is anything) wrong with it? You probably should post the query plan here too.

Comment: I have created clustered index on all the join columns...

Comment: If you want to share the plan, try https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ @Teja

Comment: The CASE statements are usually more efficient like this: `AND (l.strareabriefnamel2 IS NULL OR l.strareabriefnamel2 = tg.areacode)`

Comment: That's a case expression, not case statement. (Returns a value, instead of conditional execution of code in a stored procedure.)

Answer (score 5):

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax.

This probably doesn't change the performance of the query, but it is a much more typical way to write it.  I'm pretty sure the intention is:

```
SELECT l.*, tg.*
FROM RefTable tg JOIN
     InputTbl l
     ON tg.areascheme = l.areascheme AND tg.countrycode = l.strareabriefnamel1  
WHERE (l.strareabriefnamel2 IS NULL OR tg.areacode = l.strareabriefnamel2) AND
      (l.strareabriefnamel3 IS NULL OR tg.subareaname  = l.strareabriefnamel3) AND
      (l.strareabriefnamel4 IS NULL OR tg.postalname = l.strareabriefnamel4)
  option( MAXDOP 0 );
```

The place to start with optimizing this query is with indexes.  I would suggest: `RefTable(areascheme, countrycode)` and `InputTbl(areascheme, strareabriefnamel1)`.

Comment: To expand your suggestion, would you also recommend included columns?   e.g. `RefTable(areascheme, countrycode) include (areacode, subareaname, postalname)` and 
`InputTbl(areascheme, strareabriefnamel1) include (strareabriefnamel2, strareabriefnamel3, strareabriefnamel4)`

Comment: @SqlZim . . . I would not start with included columns, but then again, I don't fully understand the data structure.

Comment: Actually, commas mean you have a good 'ol cartesian join. Which is in the standard. so technically it is proper. Of course, being explicit provides clarity

Comment: @clifton_h That'd be true if there wasn't a `WHERE` clause with the columns being joined.

Comment: Again, that is the standard. The where clause acts as an ON predicate. Not saying it is wise or optimal, just pointing out it can, may, might be legitimate and is certainly used in legacy servers

Comment: Did you mean: cartesian join @clifton_h ?

Comment: XD yeah. Corrected. Mobile 1 User 0

Comment: @clifton_h while that it is true from the ANSI-89 standard it was replaced in the ANSI-92 standard (25 years ago). The comma separated list still exists but has been out of favor for a LONG time. It is shorthand for a cross join. The main reason is that it is so easy to miss a predicate.

Comment: the point was to correct the misinterpretation by the answer that implies a cartesian join by acceptable ISO standard is not proper syntax. It may not be "good" syntax, arcaic, but it will compile everytime. Instead, explain why it has fallen out of favor.

Comment: The best reason is so you use a consistent syntax when using OUTER joins -- LEFT and RIGHT joins. There were some symbols used for this type of syntax back in the bad old days, with code like `WHERE table1.field1 *= table2.field1`, but implementations were sketchy, readability was limited, and the returned results could differ when using this syntax from using the LEFT/RIGHT syntax - because the JOINs were not in the WHERE clause. Consistency of syntax is good enough for me.

Comment: Whether you use comma or join notation, an identical query plan will be produced (note: there will be no 'cross' or 'cartesian' joins in it though). I agree with @LaughingVergil statement - I moved to the newer syntax when I discovered that the old syntax is ambiguous when defining outer joins (as it is defined on columns, not on tables)

Comment: Exactly. And deserve to be in an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response Gordon... I incorporated this logic and ran the code but my query is taking 1 hr 22 min to complete the execution. My (new) join is between two tables RefTable(45k records ) and InputTable(466k records) is producing around 351 million rows because of the OR condition in each filter condition. I have created CLUSTERED INDEXES on both tables that participate in jon conditions but there is no luck.... Could you help me if there is a better approach to bring down the execution time in few mins without missing out on the logic.. Thanks...

Comment: @Teja . . . If you want to improve performance, then you probably need dynamic SQL (and appropriate indexes).  If you can't follow that, then you might want to ask another question.