# Long running query taking forever to execute in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is the best way to optimize the below SQL query in SQL Server. I tried adding clustered index on the join columns but there is no luck and the SQL keeps running forever. Could someone help me regarding this. Thank you.

InputTable - 466K rows
RefTable - 45k rows

```
Input Data Distribution :-

240360 rows L1( NOT NULL ),L2( NOT NULL ),L3( NULL ),L4( NULL )
225776 rows L1( NULL ),L2( NULL ),L3( NULL ),L4( NULL )
```

- Note :-

There are no NULL values in the ref table.

```
SELECT tg.guidExternal,
       tg.areascheme, 
       tg.latitude, 
       tg.longitude, 
       tg.guidremodel,
       tg.countrycode,
       tg.areacode,
       tg.subareaname,
       tg.postalname 
  INTO #tmpRef
  FROM RefTable tg WHERE areascheme = 1003


SELECT 
        l.locationsid,
        tg.guidExternal, 
        tg.areascheme, 
        tg.latitude, 
        tg.longitude, 
        tg.guidremodel AS guidExternalModel
  INTO #initFromOut
  FROM  #tmpRef tg
  JOIN
        InputTable l
    ON --tg.areascheme = l.areascheme
       tg.countrycode = l.strareabriefnamel1 
   AND ( CASE WHEN l.strareabriefnamel2 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tg.areacode END ) = COALESCE( l.strareabriefnamel2,'' )
   AND ( CASE WHEN l.strareabriefnamel3 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tg.subareaname END ) = COALESCE( l.strareabriefnamel3,'' )
   AND ( CASE WHEN l.strareabriefnamel4 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tg.postalname END ) = COALESCE( l.strareabriefnamel4,'' )
       --( l.strareabriefnamel2 IS NULL OR tg.areacode = l.strareabriefnamel2 ) AND
       --( l.strareabriefnamel3 IS NULL OR tg.subareaname  = l.strareabriefnamel3 ) AND
       --( l.strareabriefnamel4 IS NULL OR tg.postalname = l.strareabriefnamel4 ) AND
       --l.locationsid  NOT IN ( SELECT locationsid FROM #tGeocodedLocations )

Execution Plan :-
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know which of the two statement take long?

Comment: Out of interest - why are you dumping the subset of records you're interested in from `RefTable` into a temp table and joining to that, instead of just joining `RefTable` directly to `InputTable`?

Comment: If you see the code I commented out on areascheme... My input data set has data with areascheme=1003 which is the reason I separated the ref table for 1003 so that the join would be on a smaller data set.

Comment: One suggestion is using this condition on the `JOIN` :     `tg.countrycode = l.strareabriefnamel1
    AND (l.strareabriefname2=tg.areacode OR l.strareabriefname2 IS NULL)
 AND (l.strareabriefname3=tg.subareaname OR l.strareabriefname3 IS NULL)
 AND (l.strareabriefname4=tg.postalname OR l.strareabriefname4 IS NULL)`. But out of that, it seems pretty tough because your join do a lot of string comparison.

Comment: @DVT Yes I tried the above join logic but even this code takes longer.. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Teja I don't know. It depends a lot on other factors. I suggest you ask on the Database Administrator forum (sister of SO in the stack exchange). They are the pro on this stuff.

Comment: I added the execution plan for the SQL which I posted in the above post..

Comment: According to the execution plan you posted, the Merge Join take the longest of time (99%). Have you tried using query hint to force it to use other joins?

Comment: Not sure how it works.... Can you guide me how to do it...thanks..

Comment: Because you're using functions in the join, the only part of the join that can use indexes is `tg.countrycode = l.strareabriefnamel1` -- and that's probably not going to help a lot

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815.aspx Try the LOOP JOIN. Also, I noticed the name difference in the tmp Geography table, I'm not sure if it is the exact query you posted here. Additionally, try adding a clustered index (Primary key to the set of columns in your join) to your temporary table so that the table is sorted in advance.

Comment: @DVT I modified the table names to post it on SO but the query is correct. I added/removed clustered index on tmp table but the execution is still the same. The query run takes close to 2 hrs or more than 2 hrs sometimes... but I want it to execute with in a minute or two :(

Comment: With the amount of rows, it'd be amazing if you can get it down to a minute or two. Another strategy is if your Input table have a lot more columns than what you need here (5 columns), then dump the columns for the join and the locationId to a temp table and work specifically on two temp tables.

Comment: You should index your temp table to speed this up, something like this:  `CREATE INDEX ixTemp ON #tmpRef (CountryCode, AreaCode, subAreaName, postalName)`. Your matching will be much quicker.

Comment: Do NOT add a multifield primary key to your temp table unless this process is guaranteed to not be run twice simultaneously. Since the multi-field PK has to be named, running this twice at the same time will generate a PK naming conflict.

Comment: @DVT I created a temp input table with all the required columns that participate in the join condition but still the Estimated Subtree cost remains at 1835 and merge join is taking around 99% of the cost.

Comment: try to select count(1) from InputTable where strareabriefnamel2 is null and strareabriefnamel3 is null and strareabriefnamel4 is null.

Comment: @Teja As a test, how about taking a quarter of the rows of that temp input table and try running the query to see how long it take?

Comment: I ran the above query with 466k rows and it took me around 1 hr 38 mins to complete....

Comment: That's why I said **a quarter**. You can abandon it if it takes more than 15 minutes.

Comment: @Teja how many rows was in your result?

Comment: My query is returning around 350 million rows as there are NULL values in l3,l4(coming from input data). There is a cartesian product happening between input data and ref table as l1,l2 contain 'US','CA'(for eg.there could be other states too) where as l3,l4 are NULLs

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because cross / duplicate posting http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158724/long-running-query-in-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment304588_158724  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109254/optimizing-case-when-statement-in-sql-server-where-clause-condition

Comment: @Paparazzi A valid question can be closed only when there is a solution provided... Thanks for taking good care of my question...

Comment: @Teja It gets closed when it get enough votes

Comment: Thanks for the help Paparazzi :)

Comment: I really dont understand why everyone is downvoting this post... If you dont like something pls post ur comments rather than downvoting... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume #tmpRef is a address database.

you receive 45k rows (all rows from #RefTable) per each row in InputTable where strareabriefnamel2 is then and strareabriefnamel3 is null and strareabriefnamel4 is null

For example, if input table contains 1000 rows with country code only you receive 45M rows in result and so on.

you shoud rewrite WHERE condition, something like this:

```
(l.strareabriefname2=tg.areacode OR 
    (l.strareabriefname2 IS NULL AND tg.areacode IS NULL
) AND ...
```

In this case you find only countries if areacode is null, not all records from country.

P.S.
Also you should have index on #refTable on countrycode, strareabriefname2, strareabriefname3, strareabriefname4

Answer (score 0):

First, that first insert statment is just a waste of time - you could just join to RefTable in your second statement instead of #tmpRef.

Next, you are not a working with a very good design when you have to have complex join conditions on NULLABLE columns. This SELECT statement is what's killing you:

```
SELECT  l.locationsid,
        tg.guidExternal, 
        tg.areascheme, 
        tg.latitude, 
        tg.longitude, 
        tg.guidremodel AS guidExternalModel
  INTO #initFromOut
  FROM  #tmpRef tg
  JOIN InputTable l
    ON --tg.areascheme = l.areascheme
       tg.countrycode = l.strareabriefnamel1 
   AND ( CASE WHEN l.strareabriefnamel2 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tg.areacode END ) = COALESCE( l.strareabriefnamel2,'' )
   AND ( CASE WHEN l.strareabriefnamel3 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tg.subareaname END ) = COALESCE( l.strareabriefnamel3,'' )
   AND ( CASE WHEN l.strareabriefnamel4 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tg.postalname END ) = COALESCE( l.strareabriefnamel4,'' )
```

That's a guaranteed scan on both tables and an inefficient merge join in your execution plan. One viable alternative would be to create an indexed view like so:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.yourView 
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT l.locationsid,
       tg.guidExternal, 
       tg.areascheme, 
       tg.latitude, 
       tg.longitude, 
       tg.guidremodel AS guidExternalModel
FROM RefTable tg 
JOIN InputTable l
ON tg.countrycode = l.strareabriefnamel1 
AND ( CASE WHEN l.strareabriefnamel2 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tg.areacode END ) = COALESCE( l.strareabriefnamel2,'' )
AND ( CASE WHEN l.strareabriefnamel3 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tg.subareaname END ) = COALESCE( l.strareabriefnamel3,'' )
AND ( CASE WHEN l.strareabriefnamel4 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tg.postalname END ) = COALESCE( l.strareabriefnamel4,'' )
WHERE tg.areascheme = 1003; 
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX uci_yourview ON dbo.yourView(guidExternal) 
-- your unique key would likely be different this is just a thought based on what info is available.
```

Then populating #initFromOut is fast and simple:

```
SELECT * INTO #initFromOut FROM dbo.yourView;
```

The downside is that this will have a slight impact on data modification performed against your RefTable and InputTable. So your would want to do a little testing.

Comment: Msg 4512, Level 16, State 3, Procedure yourView, Line 3
Cannot schema bind view 'dbo.yourView' because name 'AIRGeography.dbo.tGeography' is invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself.

Comment: Add the schema to reftable and inputtable. Change 
FROM RefTable tg 
JOIN InputTable l
to:
FROM dbo.RefTable tg 
JOIN dbo.InputTable l

Comment: ... and you can't reference database names in views that use schemabinding. You would have to change AIRGeography.dbo.tGeography to just dbo.tGeography. FYI - If you are referencing tables from other databases then you CANT use an indexed view.